# Java - How to set my mark to 0 if the mark are more than 10?

Tags: java

I was asked by the question to set the mark to 0 if it is more than 10 ... this is my question : " to A practical mark should not be more than 10. If the mark given is invalid, the practical mark should be set to 0." can anyone help me how to set it ???

```
 public void setPractical(double practical_mark)
{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the practical_mark");
    practical_mark =read.nextDouble();
  if ( practical_mark>10)
  {
      practical_mark = 0;                                                                 
  }   
}
```

Comment: you take `practical_mark` as an *argument*, then store the *keyboard input* in that. It makes no sense to me. It looks as if you need another variable.

Comment: Do you want to set the variable taken as argument ? if you want to do this java works pass by value, you are changing another variable there

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is correct you have to return the value instead :

```
public double setPractical(double practical_mark){
   //...
   return practical_mark;//return the result, and assign it to another varibale
}
```

Then the result should be used like this :

```
double result = setPractical(practical_mark);
```

---

**EDIT**

Like @Shashwat mention in comment if you want to change the value in your method, then why you pass it like an argument in your method, it is useless, instead you can use :

```
public double setPractical() {
//-------------------------^------no need to pass your variable here
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the practical_mark");

    //just create it a initialize it in your method, like this
    double practical_mark = read.nextDouble();

    if (practical_mark > 10) {
        practical_mark = 0;
    }
    return practical_mark;
}
```

Comment: if the OP is taking input using keyboard, then what's the use of passing an argument.

Comment: what did you mean @Shashwat i don't get you?

Comment: Check the OP's code. It does `practical_mark =read.nextDouble();` within the method. That just changes the value passed by the argument.

Comment: yes @Shashwat for that i makes `//...` i don't understand why the OP want to change the input, i think changing the value of the input is useless in this case

Comment: Looks better, and pushes the OP in a better direction(+1)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have two values here, If the value comes into the function you don't need to ask the user into

So :

```
public double checkPractical(double practical_mark){
  if (practical_mark>10){ 
      practical_mark = 0;                                                                 
  }
  return practical_mark;
}
```

//can be reduce to : return (practical_mark>10)?0:practical_mark;

And be called :

```
public void main(String[] args){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the practical_mark");
    double practical_mark = read.nextDouble();
    practical_mark = checkPractical(practical_mark);
}
```

Comment: Careful with the returning type, you are casting float to int.